# Spring gateway and spring mvc in an application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring boot application.

I know that spring mvc is incompatible with spring cloud gateway and it is needed to use spring-boot-starter-webflux instead of spring-boot-starter-web.

But the problem is that I have to add a gateway functionality to an existing app.

And so I have some questions that I hope will help with the problem:

1. May I create another spring context for separate beans of this libraries? I. e., I mean the old app will work with old context and gateway only with the new. And here are another question: How can I load spring starter in another spring context?
2. May I configure another port for gateway? So that the old app receives messages on port 8080, and the gateway receives messages for itself on port 8081.